# Pull all data behind query with subqueries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the query below, which works great for telling me the differences in columns of data linked on other columns. Now I need to be able to pull all data where the sum(case) is increasing the counter to verify the results (essentially remove the groupings but only include the data I am looking for).

Also, any help simplifying the original query would be great, as it is unnecessarily long.

```
select FacilityCode, AdmitDate,
sum(case when NumFirstName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
sum(case when NumLastName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentLastNames,
sum(case when NumSSN <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSSN,
sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPhone ,  
sum(case when NumSex <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSex   ,
sum(case when NumPatientDOB <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPatientDOB   ,
sum(case when NumAddress <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentAddress   ,
sum(case when NumAddress2 <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentAddress2   ,
sum(case when NumCity <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentCity   ,
sum(case when NumState <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentState   ,
sum(case when NumZip <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentZip   ,
sum(case when NumMaritalStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentMaritalStatus   , 
sum(case when NumReligion <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentReligion   ,
sum(case when NumRace <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentRace   ,
sum(case when NumEmail <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentEmail   ,
sum(case when NumID <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentID   ,
sum(case when NumPatientType <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPatientType   ,
sum(case when NumFacilityPatientID <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFacilityPatientID   ,
sum(case when NumServiceFieldCode <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentServiceFieldCode   ,
sum(case when NumReferringPhysicianName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentReferringPhysicianName   ,
sum(case when NumReferringPhysicianPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentReferringPhysicianPhone   ,
sum(case when NumAdmittingPhysicianName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentAdmittingPhysicianName   ,
sum(case when NumAdmittingPhysicianPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentAdmittingPhysicianPhone   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorFirstName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorFirstName   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorLastName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorLastName   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorPhone   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorAddress <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorAddress   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorAddress2 <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorAddress2   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorZip <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorZip   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorState <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorState   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorCity <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorCity   ,
sum(case when NumEmployerName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentEmployerName   ,
sum(case when NumEmployerPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentEmployerPhone   ,
sum(case when NumERContactFirstName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentERContactFirstName   ,
sum(case when NumERContactLastName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentERContactLastName   ,
sum(case when NumERPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentERPhone   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorDOB <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorDOB   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorEmployer <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorEmployer   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorEmployerPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorEmployerPhone   ,
sum(case when NumGuarantorRace <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentGuarantorRace   ,
sum(case when NumHasBenefitsForResidual <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentHasBenefitsForResidual   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryType <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryType   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryPayor <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryPayor   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryPlan <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryPlan   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryAuto <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryAuto   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryStatus   ,
sum(case when NumPrimaryVerificationStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPrimaryVerificationStatus   ,
sum(case when NumHasSecondary <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentHasSecondary   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryType <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryType   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryPayor <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryPayor   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryPlan <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryPlan   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryAuto <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryAuto   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryStatus   ,
sum(case when NumSecondaryVerificationStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSecondaryVerificationStatus   ,
sum(case when NumHasTertiary <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentHasTertiary   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryType <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryType   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryPayor <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryPayor   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryPlan <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryPlan   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryAuto <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryAuto   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryStatus   ,
sum(case when NumTertiaryVerificationStatus <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentTertiaryVerificationStatus   

from (select EncounterId, FacilityCode, AdmitDate, count(*) as Num,
count(distinct FirstName) as NumFirstName,
count(distinct LastName) as NumLastName,
count(distinct SSN) as NumSSN,
count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone,
count(distinct Sex) as NumSex,
count(distinct PatientDOB) as NumPatientDOB,
count(distinct Address) as NumAddress,
count(distinct Address2) as NumAddress2,
count(distinct City) as NumCity,
count(distinct State) as NumState,
count(distinct Zip) as NumZip,
count(distinct MaritalStatus) as NumMaritalStatus,
count(distinct Religion) as NumReligion,
count(distinct Race) as NumRace,
count(distinct Email) as NumEmail,
count(distinct ID) as NumID,
count(distinct PatientType) as NumPatientType,
count(distinct FacilityPatientID) as NumFacilityPatientID,
count(distinct ServiceFieldCode) as NumServiceFieldCode,
count(distinct ReferringPhysicianName) as NumReferringPhysicianName,
count(distinct ReferringPhysicianPhone) as NumReferringPhysicianPhone,
count(distinct AdmittingPhysicianName) as NumAdmittingPhysicianName,
count(distinct AdmittingPhysicianPhone) as NumAdmittingPhysicianPhone,
count(distinct GuarantorFirstName) as NumGuarantorFirstName,
count(distinct GuarantorLastName) as NumGuarantorLastName,
count(distinct GuarantorPhone) as NumGuarantorPhone,
count(distinct GuarantorAddress) as NumGuarantorAddress,
count(distinct GuarantorAddress2) as NumGuarantorAddress2,
count(distinct GuarantorZip) as NumGuarantorZip,
count(distinct GuarantorState) as NumGuarantorState,
count(distinct GuarantorCity) as NumGuarantorCity,
count(distinct EmployerName) as NumEmployerName,
count(distinct EmployerPhone) as NumEmployerPhone,
count(distinct ERContactFirstName) as NumERContactFirstName,
count(distinct ERContactLastName) as NumERContactLastName,
count(distinct ERPhone) as NumERPhone,
count(distinct GuarantorDOB) as NumGuarantorDOB,
count(distinct GuarantorEmployer) as NumGuarantorEmployer,
count(distinct GuarantorEmployerPhone) as NumGuarantorEmployerPhone,
count(distinct GuarantorRace) as NumGuarantorRace,
count(distinct HasBenefitsForResidual) as NumHasBenefitsForResidual,
count(distinct PrimaryType) as NumPrimaryType,
count(distinct PrimaryPayor) as NumPrimaryPayor,
count(distinct PrimaryPlan) as NumPrimaryPlan,
count(distinct PrimaryAuto) as NumPrimaryAuto,
count(distinct PrimaryStatus) as NumPrimaryStatus,
count(distinct PrimaryVerificationStatus) as NumPrimaryVerificationStatus,
count(distinct HasSecondary) as NumHasSecondary,
count(distinct SecondaryType) as NumSecondaryType,
count(distinct SecondaryPayor) as NumSecondaryPayor,
count(distinct SecondaryPlan) as NumSecondaryPlan,
count(distinct SecondaryAuto) as NumSecondaryAuto,
count(distinct SecondaryStatus) as NumSecondaryStatus,
count(distinct SecondaryVerificationStatus) as NumSecondaryVerificationStatus,
count(distinct HasTertiary) as NumHasTertiary,
count(distinct TertiaryType) as NumTertiaryType,
count(distinct TertiaryPayor) as NumTertiaryPayor,
count(distinct TertiaryPlan) as NumTertiaryPlan,
count(distinct TertiaryAuto) as NumTertiaryAuto,
count(distinct TertiaryStatus) as NumTertiaryStatus,
count(distinct TertiaryVerificationStatus) as NumTertiaryVerificationStatus

from [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]

group by EncounterId, facilitycode, AdmitDate
 ) e
group by FacilityCode, AdmitDate;
```

Comment: I'm not sure which output you're looking for. Could you include a short example?

Comment: are you sure about the tags "mysql", "sql-server" and "sql-server-2008"? Is that really specific to those databases?

Comment: @EdGibbs so what the output gives me now is the number of 'defects' there are in each column (defect meaning entries where the EncounterID matches but other columns do not).  I want a query that pull all entries where there is any defect in any column.

Comment: @luksch I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Got it. I'm afraid all I can offer here are general tips... You could continue the brute force approach and wrap your query with another long query that checks each column for > 0. Not really pretty but it's effective and still fairly readable. `UNPIVOT` may also help you here but I'm not very good with it. You could also process the result in the middle tier if you have one - the basic problem is that SQL, in general, provides a lot more flexibility for working in rows than in columns, whereas with a "regular" programming language you can operate on the columns generically.